# Convert ImageProxy to depth map

Tags: android, image, kotlin, camera

I use google libs (androidx.camera:camera-*) for create bitmap. I wrote simple code

```
internal fun ImageProxy.useAndConvertToBitmap(): Bitmap{
    use {
        val imageRotationDegrees = imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat()
        val bitmap = image!!.toBitmap()
        return bitmap.rotate(imageRotationDegrees)
    }
}

internal fun Image.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val yBuffer = planes[0].buffer // Y
    val vuBuffer = planes[2].buffer // VU

    val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
    val vuSize = vuBuffer.remaining()

    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + vuSize)

    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
    vuBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vuSize)

    val yuvImage = YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, this.width, this.height, null)
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 50, out)
    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
}
```

But I want to get depth map for my task. Can i create depth map using this libs?